# A 2009 Hyundai accent that has a new starter and will turn over but won't start would be because of what?

Tags: engine, electrical

4 cylinder, 1.6ltr hyuandi accent four hours...it has a new starter and will turn over but won't catch and I have taken the whole car apart practically.. What is the problem

Comment: "four hours" four hours what running? stopped? parked?

Comment: Why was the starter replaced? Did it run before the starter was replaced?

Answer (score 2):

If a car won't start, it's usually one of three things - compression, spark or fuel, so those are the first things to check. Does it sound like it's trying to start (e.g. 'coughing') or is it just spinning freely? Is it turning over at normal speed, or faster/slower? Does the exhaust smell of unburnt fuel?

Do a compression test, and check that you're getting a spark. Check the fuel filter and pump. Check the condition of the spark plugs - do they look badly fouled?